# Importing sheets from other excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a macro that imports sheets from other excel files and then renames them after they are imported.

If I use the Worksheets.Count method to rename the sheets, I can't reset the counter after each importing task, resulting in file names with a number added at the end always increasing. However the code will work with files with several sheets.

Because of that I want to rename it with another name:

```
 ActiveSheet.Name = i & "-" & "MON" & "-" & ShName
```

The code above is working if the excel files only have one sheet, but it stops if the source excel file has more that one sheet, with error: "'Runtime 1004' cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic"

I added a variable for the source sheet name "ShName". However this is causing the error, probably beacuse the variable name doesn't change after each sheet on the source excel file. How can I correct this problem?

```
For i = 10 To max_phase Step 10
....

For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
     total = Workbooks(Macro_Filename).Worksheets.Count
     ShName = Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name
     Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
     after:=Workbooks(Macro_Filename).Worksheets(total)
     ' ActiveSheet.Name = i & "-" & "MON" & "-" & ShName

Next sheet
....

Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're doing two loops here, one for each workbook and one for each sheet. i in your code refers to the number of workbooks and remains 1 for each sheet in the same workbook. In that case you need to use a second, unique per sheet, counter if you want to accomplish what you're describing. For example:

```
For i = 10 To max_phase Step 10
....
sheetNum = 1
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
     sheetNum = sheetNum + 1
     total = Workbooks(Macro_Filename).Worksheets.Count
     ShName = Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name
     Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
     after:=Workbooks(Macro_Filename).Worksheets(total)
     ActiveSheet.Name = sheetNum & "-" & "MON" & "-" & ShName

Next sheet
....

Next i
```